# update don't work if something is not diferent

Tags: php, mysql

If i don't change at least 1 of the fields values, the update fails.

Insert works ok.

My git 
https://github.com/emerson-cs-santos/TSI-PI_2-2019/blob/master/PHP/novo_user.php

If i keep doing this:
$status = $status . ' ';
works, but it's sound me the right solution

```
-- MYSQL --
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS SENAC_PI;

USE SENAC_PI;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USUARIOS 
(
    codigo  INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,nome   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,senha  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    ,tipo   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

;

---

```
-- PHP --
<?php

// Open a Connection to MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "SENAC_PI";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo 'errado';
    return;
} 


$query = 'use SENAC_PI';
$result = $conn->query($query);

$codigo = 0;
$login = 'teste';
$senha = '123';
$status = 'Ativo';


$query = 
   " INSERT INTO USUARIOS ( codigo, nome, senha, tipo ) Values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $querytratada = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $querytratada->bind_param("isss",$codigo,$login,$senha,$status);

    $querytratada->execute();

    if ($querytratada->affected_rows > 0) 
    {
        $resposta = 'ok';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $resposta = 'erro';
    }


-- update
    $query = 
    " UPDATE USUARIOS SET nome = ? ,senha = ? , tipo = ? where codigo = ? ";
    $querytratada = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $querytratada->bind_param("sssi",$login,$senha,$status,$codigo);

    $querytratada->execute();

    if ($querytratada->affected_rows > 0) 
    {
        $resposta = 'ok';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $resposta = 'erro';
    }
```

}

?>

If i don't change at least 1 of the fields values, then query returns: affected_rows = 0

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem? I'd definitely expect that if nothing was changed, nothing would be changed.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php#116152 may be a useful resource, you can extract the information and check how many rows match and how many were changed.

Comment: Nigel Ren, that help me a lot! Thanks! I'll try and see if resolves my problem.

Comment: VLAZ, I need to know if some error occurred. As Nigel said, i try to use $mysqli->info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Nigel**, i managed to verif the result.

I was using **"affected_rows"** to valid for errors, but if the user doesn't change something, my code will return as an error.

Using **"Rows matched"** and **"Warnings"**, i can make sure that my query doesn't have **errors**.

My final code for the problem:
    preg_match_all ('/(\S[^:]+): (\d+)/', $conn->info, $querytratada);
    $info = array_combine ($querytratada[1], $querytratada[2]);

```
// Linhas encontradas com base na condição da where
$linhas_encontradas = $info['Rows matched'];

// Linhas que foram alteradas, quando os dados não forem alterados, mesmo o comando estando certo, não é retornado linhas afetadas
$linhas_afetadas = $info['Changed'];

// Avisos de problemas
$avisos_problemas = $info['Warnings'];

//if ($querytratada->affected_rows > 0) 
if ($linhas_encontradas == '1' and $avisos_problemas == '0')
{
    $resposta = 'ok';
} 
else 
{
    $resposta = 'erro';
}
```

Anyway, thanks again Nigel!

Comment: Would not it be simpler to check if your sql statekent generated an error, rather than checking mysql info results in such a convoluted way?

Comment: Hi Shadow, i need as well to make sure that my query found something. If some error occurs, it will end up in the else.